# Different timestamps for same sql query in Source Oracle Database and Target same Oracle Database while using Informatica

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, informatica-powercenter

The source is having Createddate as 17-JAN-18 17.22.39.000000000 in my table.

When I execute the following query:

```
select CAST(Createddate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS Timestamp) from Employee
```

on Oracle Database, It is giving below results.

```
17-JAN-18 15.22.39.000000000
```

But when I use the same SQL Query in Source Qualifier(Informatica) the target is getting below result which is in the same Oracle Database.

```
17-JAN-18 12.22.39.000000000
```

I am getting a 1 hour difference. Can someone help how can I get the same timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Createddate value is a `TIMESTAMP` value (without `TIME ZONE`).

When you run `CAST(Createddate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS Timestamp)` then Oracle actually does

```
CAST(
   FROM_TZ(Createddate, SESSIONTIMEZONE) 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS Timestamp)
```

I.e. it appends the current session time zone to the timestamp value and then it is converted to new time zone.

So, the session time zones are different. The most reliable solution would be to set the time zone explicitly, e. g.

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(Createddate, 'Europe/Zurich') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS Timestamp)
```

btw, for your function there is a shortcut, simply use like

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(Createddate, 'Europe/Zurich'))
```

Comment: Now i am getting same results but 1 hour extra for both

Comment: What can be the sessiontimezone('Europe/Zurich' value) for Finland?

Comment: Maybe `Europe/Helsinki`?